# Push data in Microsoft Health Cloud Service

Tags: microsoft-band

The available API provided  only exposes methods for getting activity details information. Is there an option to push data in this service ?
[Microsoft Health Cloud API](http://developer.microsoftband.com/cloudAPI)

Answer (score 3):

No, the current preview version of the Microsoft Health Cloud API does not expose a means to add data to the service.